# Display divs with different sizes with CSS

Tags: html, css

how can I display divs with different height to be close to each other regardless of its height and with a specific margin just like buildings 
I mean something like the divs in this website http://via.me 
I used flaot:left but it floats only with the last div and leaves an empty spaces
this is the code that I used http://jsfiddle.net/D9rHB/6/

Comment: Take a look here: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Hi, I came across the same situation.I am pulling my hair to get a clear output. I used masonry but failed. Can you explain me in some clear steps. please see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729070/trying-to-align-the-position-of-divs-which-are-of-different-sizes-so-that-ther

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the jQuery [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin would be what you're looking for in this instance:

> Masonry is a dynamic grid layout plugin for jQuery. Think of it as the flip-side of CSS floats. Whereas floating arranges elements horizontally then vertically, Masonry arranges elements vertically, positioning each element in the next open spot in the grid. The result minimizes vertical gaps between elements of varying height, just like a mason fitting stones in a wall.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D9rHB/7/).

Comment: actually its a great plugin, but can I do it with pure CSS ??

Comment: You can't; there's some hope, perhaps, with flex-boxes, but otherwise it's not possible without server-side scripting to calculate offsets and reorganising.

Comment: thanks buddy, I just found out this link it might be helpful for others.
http://www.queness.com/post/11133/the-famous-pinterest-dynamic-grid-layout-and-design-inspirations

Answer (score -1):

You can do that. For that you have to have position as "absolute".

Then manually calculate the height and top value  to place the div where ever you want.

For making the things easy take the width of all divs same. Also make height of divs in each

column fixed.

Let me know if you need more clarification how to do this.

Comment: thanks , but I mentioned above in the question "regardless of its height" so the height isn't the same for all divs

Comment: also the divs should be displays as a flow