# Trying to align the position of div's which are of different sizes, so that there will not be any blank spaces between them

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-masonry

Please don't consider my question as a duplicate. I just din't succeed trying [Display divs with different sizes with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387625/display-divs-with-different-sizes-with-css)

As suggested in the above post i used **Masonry**. But failed to get it worked. I am using codeigniter.

**Here are the css i am using**

```
#container {
    width:90%;
    margin:3% 0px 0px 10%;
}
.item {
    margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    float:left;
    width:240px;
    border:5px solid #f0f0f0;
    background-color:#d2dbde;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

**Javascript and js files**

```
<!-- include js files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myappdemo.com/KarmakExpo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myappdemo.com/KarmakExpo/js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#container').masonry({
        // options
        itemSelector : '.item'
    });
});
</script>
```

**content**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        <div id="usericon" style="width:240px;height:30px;">
        <!-- content -->
        </div>
        <div id="name">
        <!-- content -->
        </div>
    <div>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $picture = ($picture == null) ? '' : $picture; ?>" width="240px" height="auto">
    </a>
</div>
```

I am displaying images,name,date etc in div section

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but... you only have a single div with `class="item"`. You need to add `class="item"` to all of the elements that you want to line up, not just put them all inside a single div with `class="item"`

Comment: Yes i only have a single div which will be iterated in for loop...

Comment: I tried adding class item to every div in main div but dint worked , instead lost styling. Any other suggestion

Comment: i didnt understand ur question

Comment: Ok, so I *was* missing something, but the for loop was not evident in the code you pasted. Make sure it's generating valid html with a set of divs with class="item" inside one big div with id="container"... other than that I don't know.

Comment: My controller will have a foreach so,There by i am loading my view in foreach loop.

Comment: Look at the HTML source of your page to check whether your PHP programme (or whatever) is really producing the required HTML code.

Comment: I finally made it... Thanks @Stuart for taking time to comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Dynamic divs put in their place

[JsFiddle - Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FredGandt/nyHfC/) (number of columns depends on width of document *window*).

Since it appears you have divs of regular widths, you might try something like this:

**Note**: Since first answering with this simple demo script, I have substantially altered the linked jsFiddle demo. It now barely resembles this code, but the basics are pretty much the same.

### CSS kinda like this

```
div.column {
    display:inline-block; /* "Columns" should be only as wide as their setting, */
    vertical-align:top;   /* should sit next to each other horizontally, */
    width:240px;          /* and be vertically aligned. */
    height:auto;
    margin:10px 0px 10px 10px;
}
div.column div.row {
    width:240px;          /* All "row" divs are of the same width, */
    height:auto;          /* but of varying heights */
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#00f0f0;
}
```

### JavaScript kinda like this

```
(function () {
    var tdw = 240 + 0 + 10; // Div width + margin-left + margin-right
    window.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var ww = window.innerWidth, // how much width to play with?
            cn = Math.floor(ww / tdw), // how many columns will fit?
            cdl = [], // memory
            lc = 0, // alternation
            c = 0, // iteration
            ncd; // element object
        while (c++ < cn) {
            ncd = document.createElement("div"); // create columns
            ncd.setAttribute("class", "column"); // set their class
            document.body.appendChild(ncd); // add to page
            cdl.push(ncd); // remember them
        }
        c = 0;
        while (c++ < 100) { // this for demo // loop until there're no more
            ncd = document.createElement("div"); // create your divs
                // this could be where you add your div content
            ncd.setAttribute("class", "row"); // set their class
            lc = lc < cdl.length ? lc : 0; // alternate column as parent
            cdl[lc++].appendChild(ncd); // add the div to the column
            ncd.style.height = (200 * Math.random()) + "px"; // this for demo
                // or you could add the content via innerHTML
        }
    }, false);
}());​
```

This answer was put together whilst assuming a lot. With more detail in the question, I could have provided a more complete answer.

## Since being asked to explain...

As I understand the question, it is to find a way to take dynamic information (extracted from where is irrelevant), and fill divs with it. Each of those divs is to be set on the *page* (presumably within a "feed" container or similar) in columns. Since the width of these (lets call them "infodivs") infodivs is of a set width, we can create columns of fixed widths to contain them. Now the divs are free to be whatever height they need to be (according to the info they contain), and will simply stack up on top of each other, within their parent `div.column`.

On page `load` we measure the available width (in a live version accounting for offsets etc), and calculate how many columns will fit horizontally, then create those columns. To save reading and re-reading the DOM, we can store the columns to an array for easy look-up later.

After creating the columns, we are free to add the dynamically created infodivs to the columns, cycling through the column look-up array, utilizing each progressive column (left to right across the screen) for each new infodiv. Once we get to the last column, we set the look-up counter back to zero, and continue loading infodivs.

The method results in each column being filled with an approximately equal number of info divs (dependant on maths). There is however no check of the height of each infodiv, so any column could end up with much longer content than the others. A way around this would be to measure the height of each column as each new infodiv is created, then add that infodiv to the column which is shortest. This would result in columns remaining more closely equal in height.

**Note**: The demonstration jsFiddle connected to this answer now contains a rudimentary function to dynamically measure the column heights as infodivs are being created. In order to get an accurate reading of the column height(s), each image has a temporary `onload` listener attached which triggers the creation of the next infodiv. The listener is removed as soon as it's done it's job to free up resources. This method slows overall page loading, but not enough to be impractical. Depending on *real* circumstances, faster less accurate loading might be more desirable. In that case, discard the image's `onload` listeners and create infodivs on demand regardless of the state of those previously created.

**Further to dynamic measurement**: The loading of large amounts of data and/or images (especially images) could be improved by the addition of an `onscroll` listener triggering a function to load new data (infodivs in this case) only when the visitor is scrolling toward the end of what they already see. This would serve to reduce server stress and increase browser response. Plus: there's no point loading what the visitor may never scroll to look at.

So the code in pseudo terms is something like:

```
How wide is the screen?
Make (screen-width divided by column-width) columns.
While we have new infodivs being created, add them to the columns.
Don't add them all to one column, but shared them out equally.
```

The end result is dynamically created divs of info of equal widths, but varying heights, being laid out in a columnized fashion. Their natural tendency is to be as high up their parent as possible, so they'll always be sitting just beneath the infodiv above them.

Since the columns have their display property set to `inline`, they'll tend to sit side by side where there is space for them. A caveat is that if the width of the column's parent is reduced (after the initial layout is created), the right-most column will be pushed below its fellow columns.

As for the PHP - That's another story :-)

Comment: I am really impressed for the patience you showed. Though the logic you provided is quite professional , I will try to work on it.. Thank you very much. By the way i got it worked using masonry , But IE didn't support the plugin.

Comment: @Ramarajudantuluri IE doesn't do very much of anything useful ;-) I'd very much appreciate you accepting my answer if you find it (basically) solves your dilemma. If there's anything about it that doesn't suit, I can adapt it. Assuming you're pulling data from a DB on the server, there are functions in PHP to create DOM elements. They might simplify the creation, then just dump them into the columns. Best of luck :-)

Comment: I am not using DB. The data is rendered from a jsonAPI. This response is decoded in Controller , There by View will display it.

Comment: @Ramarajudantuluri However you're gathering the filling, you appear to be doing it with PHP (or maybe not?). If you are, see [php.net's available goodies](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) that might help.

Comment: @FredGandt If you don't mind Can you give some explanation.. I admit that i dint understand this logic, Thereby failed to use this code. and masonry nearly killed my site, I lost alignment all of a sudden !

Comment: @Ramarajudantuluri I've added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: @Ramarajudantuluri I've also updated the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FredGandt/nyHfC/) to show more closely what I think you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: No words to express.. What to say? simple thanks is not enough for your response. You made it simpler yet POWERFUL. Thanks a ton @FredGandt. Awesome

Comment: @Ramarajudantuluri You're welcome, and your thanks is appreciated. I've just added a function which reads the column heights as the infodivs are being created, and returns the shortest column element to which the newest infodiv is then added. It's not perfect, but it's close :-) Check the jsFiddle.