# Why my site lost its grid layout alignment. It's made with masonry

Tags: php, css, jquery-masonry

I created a gallery page. It displays images with variable heights. As suggested [here to use a masonry plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387625/display-divs-with-different-sizes-with-css) i used masonry plugin. It worked great till last night.

But this morning when i checked it again i lost the alignment. No alterations done to the site since past 3 days. Here is the snapshot.
[image: Check my site's screen shot here]

**Earlier**, all div's are automatically adjusted(The marked spaces were eliminated) and the display looked like

http://pinterest.com/

But all of a sudden my site lost its alignment. Unable to figure out the issue.

What might be the issue .... Please help me. In a big problem with my site

Here are the css alignment and masonry application

```
#body {background-color:#1c4d5c;padding:10% 0% 20% 20%;}
#imagesection
{
margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
float:left;
width:214px;
border: 5px solid #f0f0f0;
background-color:#d2dbde;
border-radius:5px;
}

var $container = $('#body');

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '#imagesection'
  });
});
```

**Masonry doesn't work in IE 8**
[image: Masonry doesn't work in IE 8]

Note: I am using codeigniter, Hence i am loading header, body, footer etc files in view.

Comment: Goblins, definitely goblins ... but in all honesty, how should we know without a live example, or some code?

Comment: You need to provide more details. Our local telepath is on vacation.

Comment: What is meant by Goblins ChrisR

Comment: That was sarcasm @Ramarajudantuluri, we really need more information on your issue if you expect any meaningful answers.

Comment: This looks like a javascript/jQuery issue. Please attach an URL to debug.

Comment: I used latest jquery and masonry.js but no success

Comment: @Rama raju dantuluri I think you used all css classes from masonary.. it is effecting your alignments mostly..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use only required class from masonry plugin like .box .col2 ...

Other classes might effect your total alignment..

Comment: i have only two divs one is #container and other is #imagesection i applied only for these two div's . Also if i used all css classes as you mentioned , This wouldn't have worked earlier!

Comment: @Rama raju dantuluri -- I can't guess exactly from here try to include .box class also  and if you have fire bug check the console for  any error

Comment: Hey @abhi i have edited my question with css and masonry javascript application. Please have a look. I guess some change in masonry plugin which is causing this issue. Because all of a sudden why this issue has raised? am i correct ?

Comment: @Rama raju dantuluri - Check the 'fire bug' that clearfix and masonry classes included to your div

Comment: Hi i succeeded displaying properly but, Its loading very slow. I am using only one plugin masonry. The images i am loading in div's are resized to 214px. What might be the reason behind slowness.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the surrounding container is too big. Adjust the width to something smaller again. You can see on the right border the tiling algorithm so I guess masonry works perfectly.

Comment: To take a clear screenshot and let you know the issue regarding the alignment i zoom out the screen and took the screen shot. So that miht be the reason it seems to have big surrounding container.

Comment: You mean you have responsive layout and when you zoom in the probelm persist? Masonry needs a fixed width container and cannot work with responsive layout.

Comment: The problem even persists at default zoom. I mean , to take a complete view of my site (as of now i cannot provide you site link sorry !) i took a screenshot whilst the browser window is made zoom in.